# xpath select td preceding-sibling with with matched text

Tags: php, xpath

I am trying to do the following using xpath:

1. match the text I am inputing that is in an html table cell
2. return the text that is in cell 8 of the same table row where the original matching text was found

So far I have failed.

```
echo  $bo_xpath->query( '//td[text()=247]//preceding-sibling::*[8]' );
```

I have also tried:

```
echo  $bo_xpath->query( '//td[text()=247]//preceding-sibling::*[8]/td' );
```

As well as using quotes are the 247 etc. I'm just not seeing what I am missing.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]     Without input data (HTML or XML), your question is ***incomplete***.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct xpath.

```
//td[normalize-space(.)='247']//ancestor::tr/td[8]
```

Comment: Not a bad guess (+1), but we shouldn't have to guess.  OP should post a proper [mcve].